# Bar graph code works, but results in error when trying to knit to flexdashboard or rnotebook

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is the error I'm receiving when I try to knit to a flexdashboard/rnotebook:

> Error in match.arg(method) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector calls:  ... withVisible -> eval -> ggplot -> filter -> match.arg Execution halted.

````
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library("flexdashboard")
library("ggplot2")
load("K:/Research/Jamie/R/#6/stl7172.Rda")```


Column {data-width=333}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
ggplot(data= filter(stl7172, SEX == "Male" | SEX == "Female", stl7172$MET2013 == "STL_MSA"),
         aes(x = SEX, y = INCTOT, fill = RACE)) +  
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", position= position_dodge(), width = .9) +
  labs(                                            
    title="Mean Income Level for Workers in the Leisure & Hospitality Industry",
    subtitle= "(St. Louis MSA, by race and sex)",
    caption = "(Source: IPUMS)")
````

Comment: maybe try: `filter(stl7172, SEX == "Male" | SEX == "Female", MET2013 == "STL_MSA")`

Comment: Try with `dplyr::filter`. Looks like you missed to attach `dplyr` so that `stats::filter` is called instead.

Comment: For some reason it insists that I include stl7172 before MET2013.

Comment: Oops, hit enter too soon. 

I also added dplyr:: before filter and I'm now getting this error:
Can't combine '..1' <haven_labelled> and '..2' <double>.

Comment: Take a step back. Get the data filtering done and view `head(df)` or `str(df)` to make sure what you have is what you want. When you next the data manipulation inside of your plotting code, it makes debugging a little harder.